# I convert My Xpub To Youb address And Now can't Recover Fund

Tags: electrum, recover-private-key, xpub

I convert my Blochchain.com Wallet Legacy xpub to Ypub Using
This website: [https://www.blockonomics.co/views/segwit_xpub_convert.html]

But Now I can't recover My Fund It still Stack In Given address. So what is the procedure To recover My fund From address. I use electrum TO recover it But when i give seed and create wallet it's look 30 address but None of the address where the amount was. But when i use standard key like use my ypub key it's show my Balance and I can't spend it. Its only on watch. I can't transfer fund. SO any solution About that?

Answer (score 0):

### Public keys and private keys

To spend money you need the *private* key for that money.

If you have a *public* key but don't have the matching *private* key, your wallet will show the money as "unspendable" or as "watch-only".

Playing around with *public* keys will not produce a *private* key.

---

### Wallet recovery using a seed phrase

You can recover a wallet using the "seed phrase" which is also known as a "recovery phrase" or "backup phrase". Doing this properly will regain the ability to spend money.

However Electrum uses a non-standard seed-phrase system that is incompatible with the BIP39 standard use by most other wallets.

If you want to recover a wallet using a BIP39 seed-phrase you must use a wallet program that supports BIP39. You must also ensure you are using the same "derivation path" as the original wallet. Many wallet programs allow you to specify which derivation path to use. If the derivation path is wrong, none of the addresses will match and you won't regain control over money.